Yet another "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item"
My original document is in multiple files.  I managed to whittle down my document to the smallest example that triggers the error (that's near the bottom where it says "Weird error happens here").
The "missing \item" error does not always happen.  If I tweak paragraph spacing (by either adding or removing words from a paragraph) such that it alters where page breaks occur, then the error goes away.  (This is why I left the figures in: because they take up just the right amount of vertical space to trigger the error.)
In the whittled down document below, the text has been replaced with necessary \newline commands to preserve the original spacing and page breaks. No \newlines appear in the real document.
Why does the spurious error occur and how can I fix it?
Yes, I've looked through all the other "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item" Q&As and nothing matches my document.
If it matters, I'm using TeXShop 5.46 on macOS 13.7.  In the log, it prints this info:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
...
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>

pdftex --version yields:
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024)
kpathsea version 6.4.0
...
Compiled with libpng 1.6.43; using libpng 1.6.43
Compiled with zlib 1.3.1; using zlib 1.3.1
Compiled with xpdf version 4.04

There is also the warning:
LaTeX Warning: `h' float specifier changed to `ht'.

But the only float specifier already is ht.  Why that warning?

\title{Best Title Ever}
\author{Paul J. Lucas}
\date{}

\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{courier}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[defaultlines=2,all]{nowidow}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  abovecaptionskip=\medskipamount,
  aboveskip=10pt,
  belowskip=10pt,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  captionpos=b
}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\topfigrule}{
  {\color{lightgray}\begin{center}\rule{.5\columnwidth}{.5pt}\end{center}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Best Chapter Ever}

\section{S1}

Paragraph S

x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x
x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x

\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2 \newline x
\item Item 3 \newline x

\begin{quotation}
Quotation 1 \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x
\end{quotation}

Paragraph T \newline x

\item Item 4 \newline x \newline x \newline x
\item Item 5
\item Item 6
\item Item 7 \newline x
\end{itemize}

Paragraph U

x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x
x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x

\begin{itemize}
\item Item A \newline x \newline x
\item Item B \newline x
\end{itemize}

Paragraph V \newline x \newline x \newline x

x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x
x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x
x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x
x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x
x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x
x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x
x \newline x

\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1 \newline x \newline x

Next paragraph \newline x

\begin{quotation}
Quotation 1 \newline x
\end{quotation}

\begin{quotation}
Quotation 2 \newline x \newline x
\end{quotation}

\item Item 2 \newline x
\item Item 3
\item Item 4 \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x
\item Item 5 \newline x \newline x
\item Item 6 \newline x \newline x
\item Item 7 \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x
\item Item 8 \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x
\item Item 9
\item Item 10 \newline x \newline x \newline x
\item Item 11 \newline x
\item Item 12
\end{itemize}

\section{S2}

x \newline x

\begin{quotation}
Quote 35 \newline x
\end{quotation}

\begin{quotation}
Quote 36 \newline x \newline x
\end{quotation}

Paragraph B

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor = center] () at (-0.5,0.5){\ldots};
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (9,1);
\node[anchor = center] () at (9.5,0.5){\ldots};

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd, precision=0, 1000 sep={}}

\foreach \i in {0, ..., 8} {
  \pgfmathsetmacro\x{\i + .5}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\addr{1000 + \i}
  \node[anchor = center] () at (\x,-0.5){\pgfmathprintnumber{\addr}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Memory as a sequence of bytes}
\end{figure}

Paragraph C \newline x

Pagagraph D \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor = center] () at (-0.5,0.5){\ldots};

\draw[gray,very thin]
  (0,0) rectangle (4,1)
  node[midway] {\textcolor{black}{1941}};

\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (4,0) grid (9,1) ;
\node[anchor = center] () at (9.5,0.5){\ldots};

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd, precision=0, 1000 sep={}}

\foreach \i in {0, ..., 8} {
  \pgfmathsetmacro\x{\i + .5}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\addr{1000 + \i}
  \node[anchor = center] () at (\x,-0.5){\pgfmathprintnumber{\addr}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{x}
\end{figure}

Paragraph E \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x

\section{S3}

x \newline x

\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1 \newline x \newline x
\item Item 2 \newline x
\end{itemize}

Paragraph 41 \newline x \newline x

\begin{itemize}
\item Item A \newline x \newline x \newline x \newline x
\item Item B \newline x
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={x}, float=ht]
x
x
x
x
x
\end{lstlisting}
\end{itemize}

Paragraph 42 \newline x

\begin{enumerate}
\item Weird error happens here.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


you have figures with h, so that's why latex tells you it is changing the float specifiers to ht.

don't use \newline. use paragraph breaks instead. you are telling latex it can't allow widows or orphans, but are systematically removing its ability to avoid them.

Error is caused probably in the output routine (missing item is a sort of a generic error as well if LateX ends up in an impossible, situation). Adding or removing text can help as you found out, or simply alter the page geometry by using scrbook rather than book

Guessing from your code you want to have a bigger say as to the placement of figures. Personally what I do, I use mostly  includegraphics   only in a custom environment to just allow spacing on top and bottom and captionof instead of caption. In places where I know LaTeX will move the figure properly, like in a chapter with a lot of text and a large figure I will use a float with a bp to move it to the top of the next page. I find this method easier, and needs very little fixing.

@yannisl bp doesn't allow the float at the top of the next page unless you just mean it will take the next page as a float page. but then they're usually centred.

you don't need to do anything as radical as altering the page layout or class. you just need to either ease up on the widow/orphan restrictions or provide more glue.

@cfr yes I mistyped I meant [tbp]

@cfr as far as I can see all the newline are only there for the minimal example to get the right numbers of lines, they do not replace paragraph breaks

@yannisl For figures: if documents were only 1 long page like a web page with infinite length, I'd always want the figures "inline." But in a book, I preferentially still want figures to be "inline" whenever possible; but if they don't fit without causing a huge amount of whitespace at the bottom of a page, then bump them to the top of the next page and add a small, horizontal rule below them to separate them from the rest of the text.

@PaulJ.Lucas  Pretty much what I do as well. Illustrations/photos/figures can make or break a book.

The warning about [h] is because you have two \begin{figure}[h] which should be [ht] or better [hpt]
The error from missing item is actually from the list in the implementation of the center environment in
\newcommand{\topfigrule}{
  {\color{lightgray}\begin{center}\rule{.5\columnwidth}{.5pt}\end{center}}
}

I didn't trace exactly but this is being called at a bad time, probably during the verbatim code from listings depending on exactly where the floats and page breaks happen.
Using the underlying \centering command without the center envioronment is safer here.
newcommand{\topfigrule}{%
  {\centering\textcolor{lightgray}{\rule{.5\columnwidth}{.5pt}}\par}%
}


My bet is on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/720614/2388

@UlrikeFischer ah quite possibly

But on my phone currently and can't test.

@UlrikeFischer actually no just the patch there doesn't fix it

Changing it to \centering makes it not center. \centerline keeps it centered: {\color{lightgray}\centerline{\rule{.5\columnwidth}{.5pt}}}

@PaulJ.Lucas did you include the \par I get this output

@DavidCarlisle Whoops. No. With \par, it works. But which is better: \centering or \centerline (and why)?

\centering is the standard latex command, \centering is an accidental leftover from plain tex that's not a documented latex command. @PaulJ.Lucas

@DavidCarlisle You wrote \centering twice, but I'm guessing you meant the second one to be \centerline.

@PaulJ.Lucas er yes, sorry:-)

@DavidCarlisle Due to me editing the wrong files, I didn't think the \centering change actually fixed my original problem — but it does!  Thanks! (I'm only just learning LaTex: its error-reporting is terrible.)

@PaulJ.Lucas actually its error reporting is normally pretty good and even here the error message led me straight to the error in less time than it took me to write the answer. Of course it helps if you have used the system for 30 years.

@DavidCarlisle Sure, with 30-years experience, it's probably obvious; but how one goes from a bogus missing \item (since the \item is there) to \begin{center} being the culprit to me is nothing short of clairvoyant.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
